# Docker Compose - Mapear volúmenes locales en el container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estoy tratando como dice el título de mapear un directorio que tengo en una carpeta dentro de una carpeta de mis containers, he buscado por Google y no consigo hacer que funcione

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - php:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_CONNECTION=mysql"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
      - "DB_PORT=33062"
      - "DB_DATABASE=db_selected_name"
      - "DB_USERNAME=root"
      - "DB_PASSWORD=root_password"
    container_name: phpContainer
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - php:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    container_name: nginxContainer
  database:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/database.dockerfile
      args:
        ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=db_selected_name"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password"
    ports:
        - "33062:3306"
    container_name: mysqlContainer
volumes:
  dbdata:
  php:
```

En el mismo directorio tengo una carpeta `www` que tiene el contenido del volumen `php`, y otra carpeta `dbdata` que vendría siendo el contenido de ' dbdata`, pero no se como asociar el volume al directorio local. Como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hola si te he entendido bien, y el directorio que intentas mapear lo tienes en el mismo directorio que el docker-compose.yml, deberías poner en el volumes

./php/:/var/www

./dbdata/:/var/lib/mysql

Comment: Gracias, tan pronto pueda lo pruebo. Una cosa, podrías agregar a tu respuesta una explicación para que me quede claro y no sea un copy/paste? Lo digo porque me gustaría entender lo que haces ahí.

Comment: Y si, ambos directorios están en la misma carpeta que el docker-compose.yml

Comment: Por supuesto!! Lo que estás haciendo con el punto barra, es decirle que tu directorio de php y tu directorio dbdata parten del mismo directorio en el que se encuentra el docker-compose.